# Increasing Java Heap Size

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to increase value of heap size of my jvm, but it doesn't work. Could anybody help me with this geek problem?
My configuration are follow: Windows 7 x64, 4 GB, i3 CPU

[image]

[image]

When I try something like -Xmx2000M I have nothing[image]

Where are my errors?

Comment: What do you expect from `java -Xmx2000M -Xms1000M`? What Java class do you want to run?

Comment: You have no command. What are you trying to run?

Comment: And if I want set this values by default?

Comment: I write just `java -mx2g` and I would let the JVM work out the minimum size.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are expecting this.

$ java -Xmx2000M  -Xms1000M -XshowSettings:all

```
VM settings:
   Min. Heap Size: 1000.00M
   Max. Heap Size: 1.95G
   Ergonomics Machine Class: server
   Using VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command is half correct. You need to specify what you want to run with an increased heap size. Something like this

```
java -Xmx2000M -Xms1000M -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide something for JVM to run with these new settings.

The arguments you are using only configure the JVM, it still needs whatever jar or class file you want to run.

To permanently configure JVM profile on windows, follow [these Instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/update_runtime_settings.xml). The settings tool will let you edit runtime parameters:

[image]

Comment: but if I want to set this values by default?

Comment: @user2105282 that depends on the program you are trying to run. You cannot just set global defaults.

Comment: ok, thanks! I will try to create some .bat file before running the .exe programm

Comment: @user2105282 I've updated answer, Java installs a setup tool to edit default options.

Comment: @S.D. I believe this is only for browser applets. Not for Java applications. From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html) - _It allows you to set runtime parameters for applets that run with Java Plug-in and applications that run with Java Web Start_.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify as well which class/jar you want to run. You cannot just increase the heap size per default for all java pplications. Instead you have to edit the command line of the program you are trying to run.

Comment: Depending on what the OP is trying to run there may be a system property that can be set.

Comment: hard to tell without any further context. From the question it looks like  he wants to set a new default for all java applications

Answer (score 0):

The error you have got in the last screen shot is about unavailability of the class file to run.
You should provide class file which includes main function while running java command.

```
java -Xmx2000M -Xms1000m MyClass
```

Considering you have MyClass.class in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

may be I am late)
But I think you can use it. In IDEA choose `Edit Configuration...` on drop-down list(look on picture below). And then type in `VM Options` your parameters `-Xmx2000M -Xms1000M`.
[How to find Edit Configuration on IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKdMm.png)